# What is each pin's output voltage of an ATmega328P?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, avr, atmega, output

I would like to operate an ATmega328P in 3.3V supply alongside some other 3.3V non-5V-tolerant-peripherals. I looked up in the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet.pdf) but I couldn't find an *answer* as to what is the output voltage of each pin. I assume it is the *`Voltage on any Pin except RESET with respect to Ground`* on page 303 but I would like to know for sure for both practical and educational purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right page, just didn't go far enough down. \$V_{OH}\$ and \$V_{OL}\$ are the parameters you're interested in. In practice, it will be very close to \$V_{CC}\$. If you're trying to draw some current from the pin, it will drop some. The datahseet uses \$V_{CC}\$ = 5V and I=20mA. In that case, the output voltage on the pin is guaranteed to be greater than 4.2V at 85C. If you're just going to be driving some high impedance pins on another device, you don't really need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but there is nothing on the **max** column and I just wanted to know how far above the minimum values the output voltage can be.

Comment: There is no max listed because the max is Vcc. It can't put out more than it gets in.

Comment: That clarified everything!